# Simple way to delete nested (list of 2 elements) from a list?

Tags: python

I have a `input_list = [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,8],[2,10]]`

and then i have a `elimination_list = [[1,2],[2,8]]`

I then create a `result_list` with the tuples of the input list except those found in the elimination_list

therefore `result_list = [[1,3],[1,4],[2,10]]`

I can achieve this with multiple for loops like below, but is there any way i can do this with lesser lines of code?

```
for x,y in input_list:
    is_eliminate = 0
    for a,b in elimination_list:
        if x == a and y == b:
            is_eliminate = 1

    if is_eliminate == 0:
        result_list.append([x,y])
```

Comment: You don't have tuples, you have nested lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use containment tests (`in`) and a list comprehension:

```
result_list = [t for t in input_list if t not in elimination_list]
```

The `t not in elimination_list` negative containment test will loop over all of `elimination_list` for you to see if the element is there.

If you can convert your lists to actually have tuples, you can use the faster option of *set membership tests*:

```
input_list = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 8), (2, 10)]
elimination_set = {(1, 2), (2, 8)}
result_list = [t for t in input_list if t not in elimination_set]
```

Here `eliminitaion_set` is a set containing tuples (immutable sequences) and the `t not in elimination_set` uses a hashing algorithm to determine if any given tuple is a member in average O(1) (constant) time.

You don't *have* to convert `input_list` to tuples, though; you *could* do the conversion when testing only:

```
input_list = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 8], [2, 10]]
elimination_set = {(1, 2), (2, 8)}
result_list = [t for t in input_list if tuple(t) not in elimination_set]
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought it only worked for single dimensional lists

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension with a condition:

```
result_list = [t for t in input_list if t not in elimination_list]
```

For larger lists you can use `set` for faster elimination:

```
elimination_set = set((tuple(x) for x in elimination_list))
result_list = [t for t in input_list if tuple(t) not in elimination_set]
```

The same two solutions in functional style:

```
result_list = filter(lambda t: t not in elimination_list, input_list)
```

or:

```
elimination_set = set(map(lambda x: tuple(x), elimination_list))
result_list = filter(lambda t: t not in elimination_set, input_list)
```

Comment: I don't think a set would work (lists are unhashable: try `set([[1,2]])`).

Comment: You cannot use sets unless you convert everything to tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `filter` and `in`:

```
result = filter(lambda x: x not in elimination_list, input_list)
```